Algorithm for calculating fraction from decimal with limits
The algorithm for calculating a fraction from a decimal number is known and there are enough examples for that. In my case I need to find a fraction for a given decimal where A = N/D is optimized but with given limits for N and D. This is needed for calculation the fractional part of a PLL synthesizer thats why N and D has a range given by the specific synthesizer. What could be the best algorithm to optimize this equation to minimize the error?

It will probably depend on what your limits are for N and D. Can't you just brute force all N or D to get the other?

If i understand well your question:
Having this decimal value 0.993 and i know that N must be between [2, 3] for example. And  D between [2,7].
For now, i just can imagine a brute force method like the following:
For this example we know that D > N.
decimal_result = 0.993

acuracy_step = user_defined

accuracy_result = 0.001

N = 2 #min of interval

D = 2 #min of interval

while (N / D < decimal_result - accuracy_result){

  D += accuracy_step

}

But of course it depends if N and D share the same interval.

For the algorithm to be faster, we have to set variables N and D to the closest values that would give the decimal value. And i can't imagine how to do it rigorously for now.
Also, according to the intervals, multiple values for N and D are possible.

Can we assume that the ratio between max and min is always at least a factor of 2? If so, the Stern-Brocat tree can help though it is messy.

@Gustavo   "for a given decimal " is that text, a floating point value (using binary or decimal encoding)?  Please provide more info to narrow the post.

"This question is seeking recommendations for software libraries, tutorials, tools, books, or other off-site resources." what? where?? where??? it asks for the algorithm. (voted to reopen)

@Gustavo, please provide the source of the decimal number.  Is it from a floating point variable (which is usually base-2 encoded) or user decimal text like "123.456" or some value from an algorithm, a transcendental, just some real value or what?  Depending on source, there are various algorithms.

You can use the convergents of the continued fractions expansion of your decimal to approximate the value itself, with increasing accuracy. The fractions you obtain this way will be optimal, in the sense that they are the closest approximation of the actual value for their respective sizes.
I'll use the python package contfrac for convenience to demonstrate an example below, however you could easily implement the formulas yourself in another language.
import contfrac

value = 121.79521392932
for n, d in contfrac.convergents(value):
    error = abs(value - n / d)
    print(f"{n:>7} / {d:<4}  {error:.3e}")

This prints:
    121 / 1     7.952e-01
    122 / 1     2.048e-01
    487 / 4     4.521e-02
    609 / 5     4.786e-03
   4750 / 39    3.421e-04
   5359 / 44    2.406e-04
  10109 / 83    3.321e-05
  35686 / 293   7.914e-06
  45795 / 376   1.163e-06
 264661 / 2173  6.056e-08
 839778 / 6895  6.187e-09

So if your limit was that 0 < N,D < 10000, you'd pick 5359/44, with an error of 0.0002.
EDIT
Seems the python package I suggested above doesn't properly support finite continued fractions. I've put together my own implementation below which does work, and should be fairly easy to port to other languages if need be.
from fractions import Fraction

def to_cont_frac(number):
    # fraction = Fraction.from_decimal(number)
    fraction = Fraction(number)
    while True:
        integer = int(fraction)
        assert integer > 0
        yield integer
        
        leftover = fraction - integer
        if leftover == 0:
            break
            
        fraction = 1 / leftover

def to_convergents(coeffs):
    a0 = next(coeffs)
    a1 = next(coeffs)

    hp, kp = a0, 1
    hn, kn = a1 * a0 + 1, a1
    
    yield Fraction(hp, kp)
    yield Fraction(hn, kn)

    for an in coeffs:
        hn, hp = an * hn + hp, hn
        kn, kp = an * kn + kp, kn
        yield Fraction(hn, kn)

Usage:
>>> print(list(to_convergents(to_cont_frac(1.5))))
[Fraction(1, 1), Fraction(3, 2)]


I tested this but unfortunately setting value to 1.5 for example will result in float division by zero.

@Gustavo huh, seems that package doesn't properly support finite continued fractions.  I've updated my answer to include my own implementation, which does work.  Sorry for the confusion

The convergents quickly find good approximations but can jump past the desireed range. They also miss answers like 4/6.

@btilly that's because 4/6 reduces to 2/3. The convergents shouldn't miss fraction that gives the next most accurate approximation.  If the limits on N and D require that they must be larger than some threshold, then that may pose an issue (you still may be able to apply a scaling factor to one of the reduced fractions), but I assume in my answer that its just 0 < N,D < limit

@DillonDavis Read the second comment. 0 is not usually the lower limit. Secondly, the convergents can and do miss the best. Consider the case of 0.45 with a lower limit of 0 and an upper limit of 10. Your algorithm will find 1/2 then 9/20, realize that it went too far, and answer 1/2. The answer should be 4/9, and that gets missed. You can actually get the wrong answer in both of the ways that I indicated.

If the width of the range is always at least a factor of 2, cleverly walking the Stern-Brocat tree with some extra logic can always find the right answer. But if the range of acceptable values is too narrow, this will become a much more difficult problem.

@btilly For me, to_cont_frac(0.45) actually led to AssertionError. (Btw fractions.Fraction(0.45).limit_denominator(10) finds 4/9.)

Let's assume that decimal_value < 1
If N belongs to [MIN1;MAX1].
If D belongs to [MIN2;MAX2].
Find the minimum value from [MIN1;MAX1] intersection [MIN2;MAX2] for N, now it is just:
D = N / A
You can apply the same methodology for decimal_value > 1 if you work with 1 / decimal_value
But we only get infinite solutions since:
(N * X) / (D * X) with N * X and D * X belonging to [MIN2;MAX2] intersection [MIN1;MAX1]
And there are infinite values of X that respect this condition.
